# How can I ensure my Word Document is properly converted to HTML?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am using this laravel function how can I ensure points are differentiated from paragraphs in laravel?

use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

`private function convertDocxToHtml($docxContent)
{

```
    $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'docx_to_html');
    file_put_contents($tempFile, $docxContent);

    
    $phpWord = IOFactory::load($tempFile);
    $htmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');

    
    ob_start();
    $htmlWriter->save('php://output');
    $htmlContent = ob_get_clean();

   
    unlink($tempFile);

    return $htmlContent;
}`
```